# Is there a way to update item of listview when clicking in a button?

Tags: dart, flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzLdb.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCFeJ.png)I'm creating a Listview which getting data dynamically from server. Every item has a button ' like '. I want to change the button ' unlike ' when the user click on it. I can't find a way since my items are stateless widgets.

Comment: there are many ways but first add your code of what you have done

Comment: I just created a simple listview.builder. The itemBuilder is stateless widget, it has a text and a button ' like'.

Comment: this thing wont happen in stateless widget make your widgets stateful

Comment: but ListView work only with stateless items

Comment: but you want to change the state of button so you have to maintain state

Comment: how to create a listview with statefull items then ?

Comment: see I have added answer

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
class ListViewPosts extends StatefulWidget {
  final MyResponse posts;

  ListViewPosts({Key key, this.posts}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListViewPostsState createState() => _ListViewPostsState();
}

class _ListViewPostsState extends State<ListViewPosts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.posts.data.length,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Divider(height: 5.0),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    '${widget.posts.data[position].post1}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 22.0,
                      color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    '${widget.posts.data[position].age}',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                      fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                    ),
                  ),
                  trailing:
                      FlatButton(onPressed: _onPressed, child: Text("here you can enter text according to your like/unlike")),
                  onTap: () => _onTapItem(context, widget.posts, position),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```